# Propagate m4 command line define to included files

Tags: m4

I have one m4 file that gets included by several other m4 files, call it `inc.m4`. It defines some macros. I now want to have a command line flag which changes those definitions, e.g.

#### inc.m4

```
ifdef(`FLAG',dnl
define(`VAR',foo)dnl
,dnl
define(`VAR',bar)dnl
)dnl
```

#### test.m4

```
include(inc.m4)dnl
VAR
```

When I run `m4 test.m4` I get `bar` as expected.

But when I run `m4 -DFLAG test.m4`, I get `bar` as well instead of `foo` as I'd have hoped. It seems the definition of `FLAG` from the command line doesn't get propagated to the included file.

Is there another way around this? I'd prefer *not* to do this in all the files that include `inc.m4`:

```
include(inc.m4)dnl
ifdef(`FLAG`,,define(`VAR',foo))dnl override inc.m4 for FLAG mode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ifdef(`FLAG',dnl
`define(`VAR',foo)'dnl
,dnl
`define(`VAR',bar)'dnl
)dnl
```

Please note that `define`s are between ticks.